# What is a complete book for Gravitational Wave Detectors

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, ligo, gravitational-wave-detectors

I would like to find textbook/lecture notes which include the following:

1. explain how gravitational waves are produced
2. the physical principles underlying detectors of gravitational waves (particulary  detectors using laser interferometry
3. astrophysical sources for the production of significant levels of gravitational radiation (a compact binary system)
4. outline the main noise sources which limit the performance of interferometric gravitational wave detectors
5. describe the plans for building more sensitive detectors on the ground and in space (describe how the signals from various astrophysical sources may be extracted from the data collected by these detectors.)

Comment: It's very unlikely one textbook covers all these things.  How gravitational waves are produced is covered in most textbooks on GR.  (2) and (3) you already know from the description you give and more detail would be in papers related to LIGO. (4) and (5) are described in various places including the relevant papers on LIGO detections.  But one textbook seems unlikely to cover it all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All these subjects are covered in Michele Maggiore's two textbooks:

1. [Gravitational Waves: Volume 1: Theory and Experiments](https://oxford.universitypressscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780198570745.001.0001/acprof-9780198570745)
2. [Gravitational Waves: Volume 2: Astrophysics and Cosmology](https://oxford.universitypressscholarship.com/view/10.1093/oso/9780198570899.001.0001/oso-9780198570899)

These are graduate level textbooks, often used by grad students starting to work on the subject. Volume 1 cover numbers 1,2,4, and 5. Volume 2 gives (among other things) a much more detailed account of 3.

Of course,as is to be expected in a book from 2007, the discussion of future detectors is quite dated, but it does get some of the many idea for third generation ground based detectors and space-based detectors across.

---

Some essential updates to the textbook of Maggiore can be found in the following *Living Reviews in Relativity*. These provide a graduate level, semi-technical overview of the state of the art (at the time of writing/last update) of the topic in the title with further references to more technical papers:

- [Gravitational Wave Detection by Interferometry (Ground and Space), Ginzton & Hough](https://Gravitational%20Wave%20Detection%20by%20Interferometry%20(Ground%20and%20Space)) (formally 2016 update, but has not been updated that significantly since 2000, less formal/technical)
- [Interferometer techniques for gravitational-wave detection, Bond et al.](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s41114-016-0002-8) (updated 2016, original 2010, more detailed/technical)
- [Physics, Astrophysics and Cosmology with Gravitational Waves, Sathyaprakash & Schutz](https://link.springer.com/article/10.12942/lrr-2009-2) (2009, not updated but still a useful reference for the long-term vision behind GWs)
- [Gravitational-Wave Data Analysis. Formalism and Sample Applications: The Gaussian Case](https://link.springer.com/article/10.12942/lrr-2012-4), Jaranowski & Królak, (updated 2012, original in 2005, current methods differ slightly)

Further, more special topics such as gravitational waveform prediction can be found in the complete [Gravitational waves collection of Living Reviews](https://link.springer.com/collections/cfecgihfij).

---

Very recently the [Handbook of gravitational-wave astronomy (2022, editors Bambi et al.)](https://link.springer.com/referencework/10.1007/978-981-15-4702-7) was published (essentially all of the chapters should be on arxiv in case you cannot get a copy). This is a heterogeneous collection of reviews on the topics listed in the OP. You may not get the streamlined experience of the Maggiore textbooks, but the chapters generally contain the most up-to-date information on the topics, in particular Part II has the newest reviews about the next-generation detectors.

Comment: Another reference I found really useful for learning the basics of how gravitational wave interferometers work from the point of view of an experimentalist is [Fundamentals of Interferometric Gravitational Wave Detection](https://tinyurl.com/4nnx8xwr) by Saulson. It's an older book, so it won't cover the most recent advances, but the basic principles are still very relevant. The section about how precision physics experiments exploit symmetry in their design in particular stuck with me as especially beautiful.